# Swift Parse create a user

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, parse-platform, pfuser

I'm new to swift, and I'm having a difficult time figuring out why the code on https://www.parse.com/docs/ios_guide#users/iOS isn't working for me

```
var user = PFUser()
user.username = "myUsername"
user.password = "myPassword"
user.email = "email@example.com"
// other fields can be set just like with PFObject
user["phone"] = "415-392-0202"

user.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock {
(succeeded: Bool!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
  if error == nil {
    // Hooray! Let them use the app now.
  } else {
    let errorString = error.userInfo["error"] as NSString
    // Show the errorString somewhere and let the user try again.
  }
}
```

This line

```
user.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock
```

gives me the following error

```
Cannot invoke 'signUpInBackgroundWithBlock' with an argument list of type '((Bool!, NSError!) -> Void)'
```

I can copy and paste the code for Objective-C into my project and it works perfectly, but when I try to do the same with the Swift code. I get this error message. Is there something else I need to do to get it to work properly in Swift?

Comment: Are you using swift 1.1 or 1.2? If you are using Xcode 6.3+ you are using 1.2. The Parse docs reflect 1.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution in case others are having a similar problem. The code below seems to working just fine. Now I'm just curious to know why parse.com gives the above code in their documentation which doesn't actually work

```
user.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock {
    (succeeded: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    if error == nil {
        // Hooray! Let them use the app now.
    } else {
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe the issue is because you are using Swift 1.2